# difference between timestamps in two consecutive rows in single table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want the time difference between timestamps from two consecutive rows of bellow table with single query :
[image]

I tried this query but which is very inefficient and giving server timeout...

```sql
SELECT t1.t_id                                           AS id1, 
       t2.t_id                                           AS id2, 
       t1.timestamp                                      AS timestamp1, 
       t2.timestamp                                      AS timestamp2, 
       Timestampdiff(second, t1.timestamp, t2.timestamp) AS diff 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   `track`) AS t1, 
       (SELECT * 
        FROM   `track` 
        WHERE  `t_id` != (SELECT `t_id` 
                          FROM   `track` 
                          LIMIT  1)) AS t2 
WHERE  ( t1.t_id - 1 ) = t2.t_id
```

Comment: is there a chance that you'd have a gap in your t_id field? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the table with itself, like this (haven't tried, but you get the idea)

```
SELECT t1.t_id AS id1, 
   t2.t_id AS id2, 
   t1.timestamp AS timestamp1, 
   t2.timestamp AS timestamp2, 
   Timestampdiff(second, t1.timestamp, t2.timestamp) AS diff
FROM track AS t1
JOIN track AS t2 ON (t2.t_id = t1.t_id - 1)
```

Comment: table don not have primary key. you considered t_id as auto increment which is not the case

Comment: First, a table should always have a primary key. Secondly you'll need at least an index on t_id so the join/where etc would have reasonable performance. So make t_id the PRIMARY key and maybe even your original solution will run fast enough ...

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT t1.t_id                                           AS id1, 
       t2.t_id                                           AS id2, 
       t1.timestamp                                      AS timestamp1, 
       t2.timestamp                                      AS timestamp2, 
       Timestampdiff(second, t1.timestamp, t2.timestamp) AS diff 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   `track`) AS t1 Join
       (SELECT * 
        FROM   `track`) AS t2  on ( t1.t_id - 1 ) = t2.t_id  
WHERE  ( t1.t_id - 1 ) = t2.t_id
```

Comment: table don not have primary key. you considered t_id as auto increment which is not the case...