# How to efficiently pre-filter rows in conjunction with a join?

Tags: mysql, join

I need to calculate timestamps between filtered rows in a table.

I am using a join based on a helpful answer from another question:

StackOverflow: [difference between timestamps in two consecutive rows in single table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26275305/difference-between-timestamps-in-two-consecutive-rows-in-single-table)

My problem is that my table has mixed data from multiple different objects and I expect that I need to first filter on "object_id=blah" before performing the join, because if I don't pre-filter then the join will difference the timestamps from unrelated object_id's (because it's just looking consecutively, row by row).

I need the join to do the timestamp differences based on the previous occurrence of object_id=blah, not merely the immediately preceeding row.

Looking for how to solve this query most efficiently.
Thanks in advance!  =D

I've already tried adding a WHERE object_id=blah after the JOIN, and I got the right number of rows, but the timestamp diffs were still just based on the prior row in each timestamp difference.

I was really hoping the WHERE would apply to the source table before the JOIN occurred, but clearly that isn't how this works.  :-(

```
SELECT
   t1.scanid, t1.event_id, t1.objectect_id, t1.object_timestamp, t1.object_counter,
   TIMEDIFF(t1.object_timestamp, t2.object_timestamp) AS diff
FROM event_data AS t1
LEFT JOIN event_data AS t2 ON ( t2.scanid = t1.scanid - 1);

--+---------------+--------------+------+-----+----------------------+----------------+
--| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default              | Extra          |
--+---------------+--------------+------+-----+----------------------+----------------+
--| scanid        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL                 | auto_increment |
--| event_id      | int(12)      | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
--| objectect_id  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
--| obj_timestamp | timestamp(3) | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) |                |
--| obj_counter   | int(11)      | YES  |     | -1                   |                |
--+---------------+--------------+------+-----+----------------------+----------------+
```

And with the WHERE object_id=2:

```
SELECT
   t1.scanid, t1.event_id, t1.objectect_id, t1.object_timestamp, t1.object_counter,
   TIMEDIFF(t1.object_timestamp, t2.object_timestamp) AS diff
FROM event_data AS t1
LEFT JOIN event_data AS t2 ON ( t2.scanid = t1.scanid - 1)
WHERE t1.object_id = 2;
```

Here is the original object data:

```
+--------+----------+------------+-------------------------+-------------+
| scanid | event_id | object_id  | obj_timestamp           | obj_counter |
+--------+----------+------------+-------------------------+-------------+
|      1 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:11:02.425 |           0 |
|      2 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:11:08.227 |           0 |
|      3 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:11:12.303 |           1 |
|      4 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:11:31.383 |           2 |
|      5 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:11:32.417 |           3 |
|      6 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:11:33.451 |           4 |
|      7 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:11:34.839 |           5 |
|      8 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:11:35.868 |           6 |
|      9 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:12:05.143 |           7 |
|     10 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:13:08.733 |           8 |
|     11 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:13:11.169 |           9 |
|     12 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:13:22.239 |          10 |
|     13 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:13:24.256 |          11 |
|     14 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:13:26.875 |          12 |
|     15 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:13:27.910 |          13 |
|     16 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:16:24.326 |           1 |
|     17 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:16:25.362 |           2 |
|     18 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:19:48.318 |           3 |
|     19 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:25:01.604 |           4 |
|     20 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:30:17.024 |           5 |
|     21 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:39:19.664 |          14 |
|     22 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:39:20.696 |          15 |
|     23 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:41:12.324 |           6 |
|     24 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:41:13.349 |           7 |
|     25 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:41:14.381 |          16 |
|     26 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:41:17.436 |          17 |
|     27 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:41:18.467 |           8 |
|     28 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:41:20.503 |          18 |
|     29 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:41:21.535 |          19 |
|     30 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:41:22.563 |          20 |
|     31 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:41:23.591 |           9 |
|     32 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:41:24.619 |          10 |
+--------+----------+------------+-------------------------+-------------+
32 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Actual Output (without the WHERE):

```
+--------+----------+------------+-------------------------+-------------+--------------+
| scanid | event_id | object_id  | obj_timestamp           | obj_counter | diff         |
+--------+----------+------------+-------------------------+-------------+--------------+
|      1 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:11:02.425 |           0 | NULL         |
|      2 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:11:08.227 |           0 | 00:00:05.802 |
|      3 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:11:12.303 |           1 | 00:00:04.076 |
|      4 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:11:31.383 |           2 | 00:00:19.080 |
|      5 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:11:32.417 |           3 | 00:00:01.034 |
|      6 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:11:33.451 |           4 | 00:00:01.034 |
|      7 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:11:34.839 |           5 | 00:00:01.388 |
|      8 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:11:35.868 |           6 | 00:00:01.029 |
|      9 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:12:05.143 |           7 | 00:00:29.275 |
|     10 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:13:08.733 |           8 | 00:01:03.590 |
|     11 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:13:11.169 |           9 | 00:00:02.436 |
|     12 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:13:22.239 |          10 | 00:00:11.070 |
|     13 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:13:24.256 |          11 | 00:00:02.017 |
|     14 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:13:26.875 |          12 | 00:00:02.619 |
|     15 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:13:27.910 |          13 | 00:00:01.035 |
|     16 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:16:24.326 |           1 | 00:02:56.416 |
|     17 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:16:25.362 |           2 | 00:00:01.036 |
|     18 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:19:48.318 |           3 | 00:03:22.956 |
|     19 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:25:01.604 |           4 | 00:05:13.286 |
|     20 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:30:17.024 |           5 | 00:05:15.420 |
|     21 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:39:19.664 |          14 | 00:09:02.640 |
|     22 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:39:20.696 |          15 | 00:00:01.032 |
|     23 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:41:12.324 |           6 | 00:01:51.628 |
|     24 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:41:13.349 |           7 | 00:00:01.025 |
|     25 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:41:14.381 |          16 | 00:00:01.032 |
|     26 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:41:17.436 |          17 | 00:00:03.055 |
|     27 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:41:18.467 |           8 | 00:00:01.031 |
|     28 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:41:20.503 |          18 | 00:00:02.036 |
|     29 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:41:21.535 |          19 | 00:00:01.032 |
|     30 |        1 |          0 | 2019-02-17 13:41:22.563 |          20 | 00:00:01.028 |
|     31 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:41:23.591 |           9 | 00:00:01.028 |
|     32 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:41:24.619 |          10 | 00:00:01.028 |
+--------+----------+------------+-------------------------+-------------+--------------+
32 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

And with the WHERE object_id=2:

```
+--------+----------+------------+-------------------------+-------------+--------------+
| scanid | event_id | object_id  | obj_timestamp           | obj_counter | diff         |
+--------+----------+------------+-------------------------+-------------+--------------+
|      1 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:11:02.425 |           0 | NULL         |
|     16 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:16:24.326 |           1 | 00:02:56.416 |
|     17 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:16:25.362 |           2 | 00:00:01.036 |
|     18 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:19:48.318 |           3 | 00:03:22.956 |
|     19 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:25:01.604 |           4 | 00:05:13.286 |
|     20 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:30:17.024 |           5 | 00:05:15.420 |
|     23 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:41:12.324 |           6 | 00:01:51.628 |
|     24 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:41:13.349 |           7 | 00:00:01.025 |
|     27 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:41:18.467 |           8 | 00:00:01.031 |
|     31 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:41:23.591 |           9 | 00:00:01.028 |
|     32 |        1 |          2 | 2019-02-17 13:41:24.619 |          10 | 00:00:01.028 |
+--------+----------+------------+-------------------------+-------------+--------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at your data, it seems the appropriate `JOIN` condition for your table is actually `t2.obj_counter = t1.obj_counter - 1 AND t2.object_id = t1.object_id`; this will ensure that only timestamps related to a given object are compared with each other. So your query becomes (based on your sample data):

```
SELECT
   t1.scanid, t1.event_id, t1.object_id, t1.obj_timestamp, t1.obj_counter,
   TIMEDIFF(t1.obj_timestamp, t2.obj_timestamp) AS diff
FROM event_data AS t1
LEFT JOIN event_data AS t2 ON t2.obj_counter = t1.obj_counter - 1 AND t2.object_id = t1.object_id
WHERE t1.object_id = 2
ORDER BY t1.obj_counter
```

Output:

```
scanid  event_id    object_id   obj_timestamp       obj_counter diff
1       1           2           2019-02-17 13:11:02 0           null
16      1           2           2019-02-17 13:16:24 1           00:05:22
17      1           2           2019-02-17 13:16:25 2           00:00:01
18      1           2           2019-02-17 13:19:48 3           00:03:23
19      1           2           2019-02-17 13:25:02 4           00:05:14
20      1           2           2019-02-17 13:30:17 5           00:05:15
23      1           2           2019-02-17 13:41:12 6           00:10:55
24      1           2           2019-02-17 13:41:13 7           00:00:01
27      1           2           2019-02-17 13:41:18 8           00:00:05
31      1           2           2019-02-17 13:41:24 9           00:00:06
32      1           2           2019-02-17 13:41:25 10          00:00:01
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jGdKHkVCcYWo3ZjMy4foK/2)

Comment: Thanks so much, @Nick!  Your solution is great! =D

Comment: quick follow-up, since all the context is already here.  =D  What if I want to store the TIMEDIFF result into a local var in addition to storing AS diff so I can use the the local var in a computation for another column in the join?   I couldn't work out the syntax.  I can just repeat the TIMEDIFF instead of referencing a local var, but that seems inefficient.  I'll post my inefficient code in the next comment.

Comment: @LeonShaner unless you turn this SELECT into a subquery, you can't use an alias in the same SELECT so you would have to repeat the `TIMEDIFF`

Comment: Not the exact math I'll be doing, but should illustrate why I want a local variable to store diff (in addition to passing it to the join AS diff):

    SELECT
       t1.scanid, t1.event_id, t1.object_id, t1.obj_timestamp, t1.obj_counter,
       TIMEDIFF(t1.obj_timestamp, t2.obj_timestamp) AS diff,
       TIMEDIFF(t1.obj_timestamp, t2.obj_timestamp) / 2 AS hdiff
    FROM event_data AS t1
    LEFT JOIN event_data AS t2 ON t2.obj_counter = t1.obj_counter - 1 AND t2.object_id = t1.object_id
    WHERE t1.object_id = 2
    ORDER BY t1.obj_counter

Comment: @LeonShaner that's the way you have to do it unless you write a subquery e.g. `SELECT scanid, event_id, object_id, obj_timestamp, obj_counter, diff, diff /2 AS hdiff FROM (SELECT t1.scanid, t1.event_id, t1.object_id, t1.obj_timestamp, t1.obj_counter, TIMEDIFF(t1.obj_timestamp, t2.obj_timestamp) AS diff FROM event_data AS t1 LEFT JOIN event_data AS t2 ON t2.obj_counter = t1.obj_counter - 1 AND t2.object_id = t1.object_id WHERE t1.object_id = 2 ORDER BY t1.obj_counter) AS diffs`

Comment: Thanks again, @Nick.  I'll sleep on it and see if I can figure out how to do the sub-query.  This is my first join, soo..  Steep learning curve at the moment.  :S  Cheers! =D

Comment: ! Awesome!  Wow, I've learned so much here.  Thanks again.  Cheers! =D

Comment: Hey, @Nick, if you think to copy your last comment as an answer, I'll mark it as the best solution.  It's ultimately what I meant by meant by "pre-filter" a la select what I want up front and manipulate it before I pass it to the join.  You ROCK! =D