# MySQL unexpected scope issue when referencing columns

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Building on a prior question, here (stackoverflow):  [How to efficiently pre-filter rows in conjunction with a join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54739704/how-to-efficiently-pre-filter-rows-in-conjunction-with-a-join)

The more versatile solution to that problem was provided by [Nick](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/9473764/nick), as shown below.

Of particular note is the use of the "diff" a second time per "diff / 2" and for which I have now used this concept successfully multiple times.

The problem is I have another example where it is not working and I cannot understand why.  Seems like a MariaDB/mysql "parsing" issue, but I am a newb. ;-)

Thanks for any insights.  =D

The functional / working example:

```
SELECT scanid,
       event_id,
       object_id,
       obj_timestamp,
       obj_counter,
       diff,
       diff / 2 AS hdiff
FROM   (SELECT t1.scanid,
               t1.event_id,
               t1.object_id,
               t1.obj_timestamp,
               t1.obj_counter,
               Timediff(t1.obj_timestamp, t2.obj_timestamp) AS diff
        FROM   event_data AS t1
               LEFT JOIN event_data AS t2
                      ON t2.obj_counter = t1.obj_counter - 1
                         AND t2.object_id = t1.object_id
        WHERE  t1.object_id = 2
        ORDER  BY t1.obj_counter) AS diffs
```

My code -- this works unless I try to substitute the line shown commented out:

```
SET @distance=1000;
SELECT event_id,
       timestamp,
       t1.overall_time,
       TIME_TO_SEC(t1.overall_time) AS overall_secs,
--       @distance / overall_secs AS overall_kph
       @distance / TIME_TO_SEC(t1.overall_time) AS overall_kph
FROM   (SELECT event_id,
               timestamp,
               TIMEDIFF(MAX(timestamp), MIN(timestamp)) AS overall_time
        FROM   summary
        GROUP BY event_id) AS t1;
```

Error given when I try to reference overall_secs right after it was specified as a column (replace @distance line with commented one to see this error):

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 120 in file: 'summary.sql': Unknown column 'overall_secs' in 'field list'
```

Comment: In the working example, I can see that "AS diff" on the inner SELECT is same name as "diff" in opening column specification.  And in my non-working example, the inner SELECT has "AS overall_time" which I am able to use in the outer SELECT to compute the overall_secs, but I cannot directly use overall_secs again in the outer scope.  I have also tried doing the overall_secs calculation in the inner SELECT, but there I have the same problem trying to reuse overall_time immediately.

Comment: Your problem is the same issue as with having to repeat `TIMEDIFF(...)` in the previous query, you can't use an alias in the same `SELECT` list. You can either do what you have done and use `TIME_TO_SEC` twice, or you could add `TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(MAX(timestamp), MIN(timestamp))) AS overall_secs` in the subquery, or you could add another level of nesting of queries (which I wouldn't recommend)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry SQL does not work that way.  "Aliases" are not available until several steps later.  I think the standard allows the 'columns' in the `SELECT` to be evaluated in any order.

So, your commented out line may as well be

```
@distance / TIME_TO_SEC(t1.overall_time) AS overall_kph
```

Comment: Thanks, Nick and @Rick for the insights.  I did try it both ways.  Just seemed like there should be a straightforward way not to need to keep repeating the same constructs; hoping to re-use an intermediate result right way.  Of course this is all on assumption that there would be efficiencies gained, but in a perfect world the SQL engine behind all of this would be doing some kind of optimization anyway (doubtful).  :-/

Comment: @LeonShaner - "Common subexpression optimization" is a general Computer Science problem.  I don't think MySQL ever does such.  Alas, the kludges for users (@vars, alias, derived tables, CTEs, Views, etc) only _sometimes_ help for _some_ cases.